# My bounty is about to end and I'm not sure I like the answers. What do I do?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Hello guys,

I've put a relatively large bounty (350) on [a question I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/227564/is-there-a-clean-way-to-obtain-exclusive-access-to-a-physical-partition-under-win), and now the bounty's about to end. (Just to put you all in context, I was looking for a non-crappy way to use a physical partition for VMware under Windows.)

There are currently two answers to it, and neither of them are really positive. One of them suggests creating a driver; the other suggests I resort to the crappy workaround I already had (and posted in my question).

I'm not really satisfied with the answers. I did not learn a more proper way to do what I'm trying to do, and this is precisely why I put a bounty on the question. It would feel kind of bad to give away 350 rep for no better solution. But at the same time, I don't want to be a jerk, as the guys most likely put some effort in it.

So what should I do? Should I award it anyways, or would it be fine to let it rest in peace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did not learn a more proper way to do what I'm trying to do, and this is precisely why I put a bounty on the question

If the answer is "there is no answer", e.g. "this can't be done the way specified in the question" that's certainly a valid outcome.

However, be advised that the bounty rules specify **any post provided *after* the bounty started with a score of +2 or more is eligible for auto-accept**. Meaning, even if you don't accept an answer, the system will accept one for you at 1/2 value.

https://superuser.com/faq#bounty

(and remember: ACCEPT AND BOUNTY ARE NOT RELATED AT ALL! You can have multiple bounty winners without ever having an accepted answer!)

My advice is this: unless you have a specific reason not to award the bounty (such as all the answers were weak, there were no answers, etc), it's best to award it to the best good faith effort answer and list any caveats in your comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you feel none of the answers serve your purposes or you're just not satisfied with them, let the bounty run its course.

You don't have to award a bounty.