# What if there are no good answers to a question with a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My bounty is about to end and I’m not sure I like the answers. What do I do?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1853/my-bounty-is-about-to-end-and-im-not-sure-i-like-the-answers-what-do-i-do)

Does one have to accept one of the given answers?